# Navigation is not working for quick action,

Tags: lightning-web-components, url, lightningnavigation

This code used to work but now it is not working, Now recordId is null so I added Sleep() and recordId is coming the navigation does not work. it is a quick action, maybe something related to new URL format.

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import checkUserPS from "@salesforce/apex/VFSL_ViewEntitlementController.checkUserPS";

export default class Te_trainingDeliverablesNav extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;

    @api 
    invoke() {
        console.log('invoke called recordId: '+this.recordId);
        //now do logic here for headless action.
        checkUserPS({})
        .then((data) => {
            if(data === true){
                let cmpDef = {
                    componentDef: "c:te_trainingDeliverables",
                    attributes: {recordId:this.recordId}
                }
                let encodedDef = btoa(JSON.stringify(cmpDef));
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: "standard__webPage",
                    attributes: {
                        url: "/one/one.app#" + encodedDef
                    }
                });
            }else{
                const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'User Permission Not Available',
                    message: 'This user does not have access to the page.',
                    variant: 'error',
                    mode: 'sticky'
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error in loading');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? You need to provide more information.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have edited the question can you please take a look at it now ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend utilizing the following code.
You can achieve your goal without needing to implement direct base64 encoding.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'standard__directCmpReference',
  attributes: {
    name: 'c:YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME'
  }
});
```

I hope this proves helpful :)

Sample:

1. Create lightning action ( for Contract in our sample )
   **JS**:

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class TestActionNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @api recordId;

  @api invoke() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard__directCmpReference',
      attributes: {
        name: 'c:testNavigationTarget',
        recordId: this.recordId
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<template>
</template>
```

**Meta**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
  <description>Test Action Navigation</description>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
      <actionType>Action</actionType>
      <objects>
        <object>Contract</object>
      </objects>
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
  <masterLabel>Test Action Navigation</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

2. Create navigation target
   **JS**:

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class TestNavigationTarget extends LightningElement {
  recordId;

  @wire(CurrentPageReference)
  currentPageReference;

  connectedCallback() {
    this.recordId = this.currentPageReference.attributes.recordId;
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Navigation Target" icon-name="custom:custom63">
    <h1 class="slds-m-left_large">Record ID: {recordId}</h1>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Meta**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
  <description>Test Navigation Target</description>
  <isExposed>false</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Test Navigation Target</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**DEMO**:
Action on Contract record:
[image: Action on Contract record]

Invoke action:
[image: Invoke Action]

Comment: This is not working, also recordId is not used anywhere like the above one any idea or workaround on that ?

Comment: @ShashwatChaturvedi I've added a sample to the answer. Please don't hesitate to ask any questions in the comment section.